# Log4Net SMTP Appender with Gmail

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, log4net, appender

I am using this code. It gives no error, although I have Log4Net debugging enabled. I don't receive an email either. Any ideas?

I replaced the login credentials and from / to with placeholders.

```
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <authentication value="Basic" />
      <to value="to" />
      <from value="from" />
      <subject value="Log message" />
      <username value="myusername" />
      <password value="mypass" />
      <smtpHost value="smtp.gmail.com" />
      <port value="587"/>
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <EnableSsl value="true"/>
      <lossy value="true" />
      <threshold value="FATAL"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%logger]%newlineUsername: %property{username}%newline%level - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: have you added the <appender-ref> for this new appended? Add the rest of the config file as well. What you posted until now seems ok.

Comment: log4net is designed never to throw exceptions. What's in the debug output?

Comment: @TudorCarean I have.

Comment: @stuartd When I use port 465 it says: `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required`

Comment: That's a different port from the one in your config. I think you need to use port 587 anyway.

Comment: `log4net:ERROR [SmtpAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Appender [SmtpAppender] is Lossy but has no Evaluator. The buffer will never be sent!`

Comment: set lossy to false or add an eval

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting the following into your appSettings node.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

It will then output diagnostics such as

```
log4net: Setting Property [From] to String value [tomas@kodi.is]
log4net: Setting Property [Subject] to String value [Kodiak OMS Shortcode service]
log4net: Setting Property [SmtpHost] to String value [mail.sip.is]
log4net: Setting Property [Port] to Int32 value [25]
log4net: Setting Property [BufferSize] to Int32 value [1]
log4net: Setting Property [EnableSsl] to Boolean value [True]
log4net: Setting Property [Threshold] to Level value [DEBUG]
log4net: Setting Property [Lossy] to Boolean value [False]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format  [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%utcdate [%level] - %message%newline%exception]
log4net: Converter [utcdate] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [] - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [exception] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: Created Appender [EmailLog]
log4net: Adding appender named [EmailLog] to logger [EmailLogger].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
log4net:ERROR [SmtpAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Error occurred while sending e-mail notification.
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Server does not support secure connections.
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender.SendEmail(String messageBody)
   at log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
```

Answer (score 0):

i know it is late but replace

```
 <threshold value="FATAL"/>
```

with

```
<evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="ERROR" />
      </evaluator>
```